# How to make multiple aggregate column in pivot table using one column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, pivot

I wants to show the cost and sales by year.

**Error msg:**

> The column name "2016" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
>
> The column name "2017" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
>
> The column '2016' was specified multiple times for 'pivSales'.

**Note**

> I can understand why it shows error, But I don't know the way to get an output in my scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for the PIVOT.  Just apply a conditional aggregation

```
select 
    StoreID,
    Department.Name Department,
    Category.Name Category, 
    Sum(case when Year(Time)=2016 then ExtendedCost end) [Cost(2016)],
    Sum(case when Year(Time)=2017 then ExtendedCost end) [Cost(2017)],
    Sum(case when Year(Time)=2016 then ExtendedPrice end) [Sales(2016)],
    Sum(case when Year(Time)=2017 then ExtendedPrice end) [Sales(2017)],
from F_itemDailySalesParent
Inner join item with(Nolock) on item.id = F_itemDailySalesParent.ItemID
Left join Department with(Nolock) on Department.ID = item.DepartmentID
Left join Category with(Nolock) on Category.ID =item.CategoryID
where DATEPART(yyyy,Time) in (2016,2017)
group by StoreID,Department.Name,Category.Name
order by StoreID
```

> **Edit - Using your original query and applying a PIVOT**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select StoreID
              ,Department
              ,Category
              ,B.*
         From (
                select 
                    DATEPART(yyyy,Time) Years,
                    StoreID,
                    Department.Name Department,
                    Category.Name Category, 
                    Sum(ExtendedCost) Cost,
                    sum(ExtendedPrice) Sales
                from F_itemDailySalesParent
                Inner join item with(Nolock) on item.id = F_itemDailySalesParent.ItemID
                Left join Department with(Nolock) on Department.ID = item.DepartmentID
                Left join Category with(Nolock) on Category.ID =item.CategoryID
                where DATEPART(yyyy,Time) in (2016,2017)
                group by DATEPART(yyyy,Time),StoreID,Department.Name,Category.Name
              ) A
         Cross Apply ( values (concat('cost(',Years,')'),Cost)
                             ,(concat('sales(',Years,')'),Sales)
                     ) B (Item,Value)
      ) src
 Pivot (sum[Value]) For [Item] in ([cost(2016)],[cost(2017)],[sales(2016)],[sales(2017)] ) p
```

Comment: Now I got it how you got **27.8K reputations**. Thank you genius

Comment: @mohamedfaiz "genius"?  I'm sure my wife would dispute that.  Thanks for the grin

Comment: can you tell me Is it possible in pivot to make multiple aggregate in same column?

Comment: @mohamedfaiz Sure it is possible via pivot.  Give me a moment to append my answer

Comment: @mohamedfaiz See update, but I truly believe the conditional aggregation would be performant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148928/discussion-between-mohamed-faiz-and-john-cappelletti).